# How to handle a view controller independantly in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My app's root is a `UITabBarController` with 5 sections, each of them contains a `UINavigationController`.

I also want to add a chat feature in the app, that could be accessed with a `rightBarButton` present in every navigation bar of the app. I would like it to show a chat `UIViewController` on the screen, unselecting the currently selected tab bar item and without losing the navigation state of the five navigation controllers, even the one that was previously selected before tapping the chat button. What would be my best bet to do it?

Thanks for your help/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** In your storyboard add a ChatViewController 
  - Embed your ChatViewController in Navigation View Controller if you wanna have a navigation bar. Add a close BarButtonItem in your ChatViewController.

**Step 2:** Create a close Action in your ChatViewController and binding with BarButtonItem in the StoryBoard.

```
@IBAction func CloseAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Step 3:**
In storyboard, select the Navigation Controllers with the rightBarButton and choose **Present Modally** and connect to Navigation Controller of the ChatViewController.

You can go to the ChatViewController without losing the navigation state  of any navigation controller.

Comment: Well I don't use storyboards in my app but you led me to the solution : when I tap the chat button I replace the app delegate's `rootViewController` with the chat view controller, in which I have added a tab bar that looks exactly the same than in my app's root. Then when the user taps the tab bar I replace the `rootViewController` again with the root, updating the selected index.